# _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just upgraded from RN 0.63.2 to 0.64.2 then to 0.65.0-rc.3. Now I started to get this exception while trying to navigate between screens: **_reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not a function**.

[image]

The problem seems to be in BottomTabBar.js. The code snippet is below.

[image]

The React-navigation version is 4.4.0. React-navigation-tabs version is 1.2.0.

I checked the Keyboard class' methods and actually, I CAN see a method called "removeListener". Even the auto-complete shows it.

[image]

Also, I can see in the react-native documentation that this method exists:

[image]

So, I don't see why I am getting this exception. Any help is much appreciated.

Updating the react-navigation version could be a solution, not sure about that, but I would like to avoid that path if possible since it has been working perfectly till now.

Thanks.

**Edit**: Just realized this exception is not thrown when navigating to a screen for the first time. It is thrown when I revisit a screen that has been previously visited.

**Edit2**: I am seeing this behavior on android. Haven't been able to compile the project on iOS yet.

**Edit3**: `npm list react-native-tab-view` command shows different versions for **react-native-tab-view**

```
├── react-native-tab-view@2.15.1
├─┬ react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0
│ └── react-native-tab-view@1.4.1
└─┬ react-navigation-tabs@1.2.0
  └── react-native-tab-view@1.4.1
```

I did `npm install react-native-tab-view@1.4.1` but nothing changed. I mean the output of the above npm list command changed and it all showed version 1.4.1 for react-native-tab-view but the behavior did not change.

Answer (score 7):

removeListener method has been deprecated. It is suggested to call remove on the subscriptionEvent rather than calling removeListener.

Replace those lines as follows and use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to commit your changes -

```js
   componentDidMount() {
     if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        this.keyboardWillShow = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this._handleKeyboardShow);
        this.keyboardWillHide = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this._handleKeyboardHide);
     } else {
        this.keyboardDidShow = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._handleKeyboardShow);
        this.keyboardDidHide = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._handleKeyboardHide);
     }
   }
 
   componentWillUnmount() {
     if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        this.keyboardWillShow?.remove();
        this.keyboardWillHide?.remove();
     } else {
        this.keyboardDidShow?.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHide?.remove();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

This fixed my issue:

modify node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/lib/MessageContainer.js

```
this.attachKeyboardListeners = () => {
    const { invertibleScrollViewProps: invertibleProps } = this.props;
    if (invertibleProps) {
-        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillShow);
-        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidShow);
-        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillHide);
-        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidHide);
+        this.willShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillShow);
+        this.didShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidShow);
+        this.willHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillHide);
+        this.didHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidHide);
    }
};
this.detachKeyboardListeners = () => {
    const { invertibleScrollViewProps: invertibleProps } = this.props;
-    Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardWillShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillShow);
-    Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidShow);
-    Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardWillHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardWillHide);
-    Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', invertibleProps.onKeyboardDidHide);
+    this.willShowSub?.remove();
+    this.didShowSub?.remove();
+    this.willHideSub?.remove();
+    this.didHideSub?.remove();
};
```

then, run:

```
# run patch-package to create a .patch file
npx patch-package react-native-gifted-chat
```

```
# commit the patch file to share the fix with your team
git add patches/some-package+0.16.3.patch
git commit -m "fix MessageContainer.js in react-native-gifted-chat"
```

Based on this response:
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/2090#issuecomment-901812607

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issues, allowed me to down grade the library until the maintainers get the kinks worked out of the latest version and patch around what was deprecated by latest versions of RN.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while I used `"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.4"`. I found that issue file was in react-native-paper@3.12.0 package. I have just updated it to react-native-paper@4.12.5 and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this modifying the file in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/Keyboard.js and persisting the change using the [patch-package library](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#readme)

You need rename the `removeEventListener` function to `removeListener`

Then you run in the project folder:

```
yarn patch-package react-native
```

This will create a patches folder in the root and a file with the changes. That's it.