# TypeError: _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm having a weird error, the function _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not in my code, neither in the dependencies inside my project, I don't understand what is causing the error, it appear when I navigate from one view to another one, here is the complete error log:

```
ERROR  Warning: Internal React error: Attempted to capture a commit phase error inside a detached tree. This indicates a bug in React. Likely causes include deleting the same fiber more than once, committing an already-finished tree, or an inconsistent return pointer.

Error message:

TypeError: _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not a function (it is undefined)
    in BottomTabBar (created by BottomTabView)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
```

and the navigation code:

```
const handlerLogout = () => {
    dispatch(clientsActions.unsetClients());
    dispatch(loansActions.unsetLoans());
    dispatch(userActions.unsetUser());
    dispatch(expensesActions.unsetExpenses());
    dispatch(changesActions.unsetChanges());
    props.navigation.navigate('Calculator');
}
```

If I comment all the dispatch actions and let there only the props.navigation.navigate('Calculator'); the error is still there

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696600/reactnative-keyboard-removelistener-is-not-a-function

Comment: @DinhNguyen it's not the same since I'm not calling Keyboard.removeListener anywhere in my code like the guy from that question

Comment: You can use solution in the answer of this, because your issue is some of your library is use `Keyboard.removeListener`, what has been deprecated in `react-native`

Comment: @DinhNguyen like I said in the question "I'm having a weird error, the function _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not in my code, neither in the dependencies inside my project"

Comment: Yes. This error occurs because your `BottomTabBar` use the function `_reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener` in their modules, so that is why the error appear when you navigate screen

Comment: @DinhNguyen bro I don't know how to explain to you that _reactNative.Keyboard.removeListener is not in my code neither in the modules that I use or the modules that those modules use, I'm not using BottomTabBar, the most similar thing that I use is import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'; but it's different from BottomTabBar